# Serve local Django app in HTML File

Tags: html, django

I want to see how some changes in my Django app will interact with an HTML page, but I don't want to deploy them until I test.
Here's my naive attempt, which doesn't render anything inside the iframe, even though that link works in its own tab.

**HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>

    <div class="frame">
      <img id="logo" src="images/Logo.png"/>
      <iframe id="primaryVideo" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/1/">
        <p> Your browser does not support iframes. </p>
      </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this website loaded with `https://`? Then the browser would prevent loading the page from localhost with `http://`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-origin resource sharing was the problem. You can check if this affects you by checking the console or network tab. 
All I had to do was add my localhost address to the `ALLOWED-HOSTS` field in `settings.py` of my Django app.